# Infinite Sum and Convergence of Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

It is known that,

$$f(x)=\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { n }{ 2^{ n-1 }}x^{n-1}   } $$

Has a convergent radius of $\rho=2$. Put,

$$f(x)=\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { n }{ 2^{ n-1 } } x^{ n-1 } } ,x\in ]-2,2[$$

i) Show that for $|x|<2$,

$$\int _{ 0 }^{ x }{ f(t)dt=\frac { 2x }{ 2-x }  } $$

ii) Is the sum $f(x)=\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { n }{ 2^{ n-1 }}x^{n-1}   } $ convergent for $x=±2$?

**MY QUESTIONS**
In the first question, I do not understand what is the function $f(t)$. I know that,

$$\int _{ a }^{ b }{ \sum { f(x)dx } = } \sum { \int _{ a }^{ b }{ f(x)dx }  }$$
I used that by calling $n$ -> $t$ and then solving for the sum. But still didnt get the correct answer as given above.

Comment: The function $f(t)$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}t^{n-1}$; you are plugging in $t$ for $x$ in the function defined above.

Comment: $f(t)$ is the same as $f(x)$, but with the variable $t$ instead of $x$ (in particular, there is no sum of $f(x)$ inside the integral as $f(x)$ itself is the sum). Aside from this observation, $f(x)$ can be explicitly written in terms of elementary functions since it is the derivative of a geometric series. --- One nitpick, in $(i)$, the left-hand side is a number while the right-hand side depends on $x$. Something is amiss here.

Comment: as for (ii), the answer is no for both values, since $\sum_{1}^{\infty}n$ and $\sum_{1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n$ diverge

Comment: The upper limit on the integral in (i) is supposed to be $x$ not $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the step you are looking for.

**Hint**. 
We may start with the standard *finite* evaluation:
$$
1+x+x^2+...+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1. \tag1
$$ Then by differentiating $(1)$ we have
$$
1+2x+3x^2+...+nx^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{-(n+1)x^{n}}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1, \tag2
$$ and by making $n \to +\infty$ in $(2)$, using $|x|<1$, we get

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \tag3
$$
giving

> $$
> f(t)=\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { n }{ 2^{ n-1 }}t^{n-1}   }=\frac{4}{(2-t)^2},\qquad t\in ]-2,2[. \tag4
> $$

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

I still do not understand where you got equation (1) from. Is this an example on how I can solve my problem or have you solved my problem for f(t). I am sorry I am just very confused for this :/